# Decompiling an ARM asm back to C

Tags: c, assembly, arm, decompiler

I wrote a nice ARM assembler routine a few years back and it has done its job beautifully over the years on the ARM embedded systems it was designed for.  Now, the time has come to port it on to non-ARM systems and I was wondering if there was tool or some sort of method to take my original ARM assembler source and get a rudimentory C file from it.  I could probably do it myself in a couple of days, but it would be nice to have a starting point.  Nicer still if the app or method was free :)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt you will have much luck.  Decompilers can "cheat" a little bit by knowing a little bit about how a compiler generates assembly from code.  Since your code is hand written, it is likely that it behaves a least a little bit different than what would be expected from compiler generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know such a tool unfortunately... Would be nice... ; )

So the only suggestion I can give is to concentrate on the logic.

You wrote assembly code. So you know what to code is supposed to do. Converting it to C code shouldn't be that hard, even with ARM assembly.

I mean porting C to ARM assembly can be a difficult task. But for the reverse option, if you know the code logic, and if you know how to write C, it should be just ok...

Creates C structures to ease the memory regions you are working with. About the algorithms, they won't change. Just translate what you are doing from assembly to C, with the help of some structs, etc...

Sorry I can give you such a tool...

Good luck : )

Comment: That's kinda what I figured.  I'll leave this question open for another day and then give you credit if no one else finds something better :)

Answer (score 3):

Hex-Rays Decompiler plugin for IDA Pro can decompile ARM. It's somewhat expensive, so probably not the best choice if you need just one routine.

Comment: Yeah, overkill for what I need(ed).  I ended up just byting the bullet and decompiling it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Several decompilers exist to reverse Arm and Arm 64-bit code to C. Aside from what's mentioned in earlier responses, two other professional options are:

- [JEB Pro](https://www.pnfsoftware.com): commercial (a free Community Edition exists, but it provides x86 decompilers only), usually has great results, especially when it comes to deobfuscating and cleaning-up protected code.
- [GHIDRA](https://ghidra-sre.org): free/open-source, developed by the NSA, fast, solid results as well, although the code is not necessarily cleaned-up as thoroughly as what JEB can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [radare2](https://github.com/radareorg/r2dec-js) decompiler plugin (`r2dec`), it convert asm to pseudo-C. But I think converting manually very interesting.